# Ternary operator in System.out

Tags: java

I found below `sysout` in our project and it is always printing 'Not Null'. Even I have initialize the `Val` variable or not, it is printing 'Not Null'.

Also why it is not printing the "mylog" in front? Can someone explain?

```
String Val = null;
System.out.println("mylog : " + Val!=null ? "Not Null" :"Is Null");
```

Comment: Nobody's posted it yet but I thought it would be relevant: [Java Operator Precedence table.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 7):

Use paranthesis:

```
   System.out.println("mylog : " + (Val!=null ? "Not Null" :"Is Null"));
```

Otherwise it gets interpreted as:

```
  whatToCheck = "mylog: " + val
  System.out.println(whatToCheck !=null ? "Not Null" : "Is Null"
```

which evaluates to something like "mylog: null" or "mylog: abc".
And that is always a non-null String.

Answer (score 7):

```
"mylog : " + Val!=null
```

will be evaluated to

```
"mylog : null"
```

which is not `null`.

Parenthesis for the rescue.

Why is `null` converted to the String `"null"`? See the [**JLS - 15.18.1.1 String Conversion**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.1):

> ... If the reference is `null`, it is converted to the **string** `"null"`

Also it's very important to understand that this is happening because of [Java operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use brackets around your expression:

```
System.out.println("mylog : " + (Val!=null ? "Not Null" :"Is Null"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it following way:

```
String Val = null;
System.out.println("mylog : " + (Val!=null ? "Not Null" :"Is Null"));
```

**Output :**

```
mylog : Is Null
```